# Combine two tables in one without using join

Tags: mysql, join

There are two different tables which i want them to combine in one:

Table1:

```
+-------------+------------+  
| ProdCode    | QTY        |  
+-------------+------------+  
| 1           | 1          |  
+-------------+------------+
| 2           | 4          |  
+-------------+------------+    
| 3           | 4          |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 4           | 5          |  
+-------------+------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+-------------+------------+  
| MatCode     | QTY        |  
+-------------+------------+  
| ZZ          | 21         |  
+-------------+------------+
| AA          | 44         |  
+-------------+------------+    
| RR          | 44         |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| QQ          | 52         |  
+-------------+------------+
```

Final result:

```
+-------------+------------+  
| Code        | QTY        |  
+-------------+------------+  
| 1           | 1          |  
+-------------+------------+
| 2           | 4          |  
+-------------+------------+    
| 3           | 4          |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 4           | 5          |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| ZZ          | 21         |  
+-------------+------------+
| AA          | 44         |  
+-------------+------------+    
| RR          | 44         |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| QQ          | 52         |  
+-------------+------------+
```

Is it possible to do that if ProdCode and MatCode are not in relation?

Comment: `4           | 52      ` is that a typo ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I made changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ProdCode, QTY FROM [table1]
UNION ALL
SELECT MatCode, QTY FROM [table2]
```

This will select the records from both tables and return them as one result set.